# Where is the makefile located in order to install PostgreSQL extensions?

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I'm following the installation instructions for an open-source audio identification server here:

https://github.com/lalinsky/acoustid-server/blob/master/README#L40

With some modifications to the initial steps here's what I've done so far

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib postgresql-server-dev-8.4
sudo apt-get install python-sqlalchemy python-werkzeug python-jinja2
sudo apt-get install python-openid python-markdown python-acoustid
sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2 python-redis
```

However for the next step where i need to **Compile and install the included PostgreSQL extension:** using the following command

```
 $ cd postgresql
 $ sudo make install clean
 $ cd ..
```

When I run `$ cd postgresql` I get `bash: cd: postgresql: No such file or directory`

Running `whereis postgresql` returns these directories `postgresql: /etc/postgresql /usr/lib/postgresql /usr/include/postgresql /usr/share/postgresql`  However I could not find the place to run `sudo make install clean` in any of these directories.

I'm running ubuntu 12.04 from an ec2 instance here: http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/precise/current/

*Where is the makefile located in order to install PostgreSQL extensions?*

Comment: Gah. `sudo make install clean`. That should perhaps be `make clean; make; sudo make install`. You don't want to do the compile or *especially* the clean as root.

Comment: @CraigRinger the problem is I don't know what directory to run that command in.  What is the full path of the directory I am to run `make clean; make; sudo make install` in?

Comment: Output of `pg_config --version` is `PostgreSQL 8.4.14`

Comment: (Yeah, just realized that you weren't getting to the point of actually running the makefile). Did you `cd` into the checked out sources directory before running `cd postgresql`? The `postgresql` directory is a *sub-directory of the directory of sources you checked out*.

Comment: I didn't check out any sources, all I did was run the above commands in sequence from a fresh box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check the source code out from `git` before you can compile it.

```
apt-get install git
git clone git://github.com/lalinsky/acoustid-server.git 
cd acoustid-server/postgresql
make clean
make
sudo make install
cd ..
```

(the last give lines are equivalent to the three lines `cd postgresql`, `sudo make clean install` and `cd ..` in the README).

Comment: Wow ty - I've never checked anything out of git before, so this was a good learning experience for me.  Thanks for following up through comments since it helped come to a solution faster!

Comment: What's the correct syntax for checkout?  I get `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` when running `git checkout git://github.com/lalinsky/acoustid-server.git`

Comment: @user784637 That's embarrassing. My old `svn` habits came back to bite me. `git clone` not `git checkout`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, you've been a great help Craig!